# How expensive is it to set up a Netty Client and tear it down

Tags: client, netty

I am building an application that allows multiple concurrent clients to submit queries against data that is scattered over multiple Data Nodes.

There are three tiers to the architecture: clients (eg browser based clients, command line clients, java clients) submit requests to a middle tier query engine.  The middle tier query engine does query parsing, query planning and is responsible for query execution.  Query execution involves retrieving data from the data tier (a set of data nodes running in a cluster).

I use Google Protocol Buffers to serialize the query requests and the result sets between the middle tier and the data tier.  I use Netty NIO to send the GPB over TCP sockets between Netty clients running on the middle tier and Netty servers running on the data tier (one Netty server per data node).

Each data node has a Netty server to receive the request from the middle tier and respond with results.

Each query running in the middle tier talks to each data node in parallel.  I could have N simultaneous queries executing, each query talking to M data nodes.

I am trying to understand how expensive it is to set up and tear down Netty clients.  This will help me decide between a couple of different architectural options I am considering for organizing Netty clients in the middle tier.

Option 1: Each query would have its own set of Netty clients to talk to the data nodes.  In this option, when I set up the query execution for a given query, I would instantiate M Netty clients (each client talking to the Netty server running on one of data nodes on behalf of that query).  This would imply that I have MxN Netty client instances being setup and torn down as queries are submitted and completed.  Although this is the simplest approach conceptually, if it is reasonably expensive to instantiate Netty clients, this would not be feasible.  I am worried about generating too much garbage as well as a bit concerned about adding latency to the query by setting up M Netty clients.

Option 2: Have at the middle tier one Netty client per data node and share that client between the queries.  This would mean M Netty clients would be created in the middle tier when the middle tier starts.  As queries are submitted they would share that pool of Netty clients, each Netty client would need to multiplex the requests and responses between the different clients.  This is a more complicated design for the Netty client (to keep track of which responses corresponded to which query) but would generate less garbage and would impose little additional latency to the queries.

Does anyone have a sense on how expensive option 1 might be?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you share the NioEventLoopGroup it is very cheap to setup and teardown the clients. This is all you should remember

Answer (score 0):

To create a Netty channel and make a connection attmpt, you need the following:

1. Create an event loop
2. Create a bootstrap and configure it
3. Make the actual connection attempt
4. Close the channel
5. Shut down the event loop

The most expensive steps are 1 and 5.  The other steps are very cheap or pretty much close to using raw NIO API.

A great news is that the step 1 and 5 don't need to be done for every connection attempt.  You can create an event loop, and then reuse it until your application terminates.  You can run the step 5 when your application terminates, just once.